# Change hostname in tnsnames.ora file

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, oracle-database, oracle

I'm trying to write a script to update just the hostname in the tnsnames.ora file.

I'm needing the entry to work case insensitive. For example ${DBNAME} is lowercase database name and in my tnsnames.ora file it has capital and lowercase entries i.e DEV and dev, DEV1 and dev1.

Any ideas how to make this part (${DBNAME}.WORLD|${DBNAME}1.WORLD) case insensitive?

```
sed -re "/^(${DBNAME}.WORLD|${DBNAME}1.WORLD) =/,/^$/s/HOST = ${HOSTNAME}/HOST = ${NEW_DBIP_NAME}/" ${TNS_ADMIN}/tnsnames.ora
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `i` modifier? Also, please add an example complete with input file excerpt and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
sed -re "/^(${DBNAME}.WORLD|${DBNAME}1.WORLD)/I
```

The I should make it case insensitive. Add in a g if you want to make it global.